# How to get current drilldown's id in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a drilldown Highcharts graph as follow:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Basic drilldown'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Animals',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'animals'
        }, {
            name: 'Fruits',
            y: 2,
            drilldown: 'fruits'
        }, {
            name: 'Cars',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'cars'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'animals',
            data: [
                ['Cats', 4],
                ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'fruits',
            data: [
                ['Apples', 4],
                ['Oranges', 2]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'cars',
            data: [
                ['Toyota', 4],
                ['Opel', 2],
                ['Volkswagen', 2]
            ]
        }]
    }
});
```

You can have a look at it here:[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/basic/).

When user selects a column and the drilldown chart is displayed, how do I get the current drilldown's id and data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326026/how-to-get-current-level-on-drilldown-event-in-highcharts-treemap

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using highcharts `events:drilldown` trigger.

by adding this in the chart section

```
chart: {
            type: 'column',
            events: {
                drilldown: function (e) {
                    console.log(e.seriesOptions.id);
                    console.log(e.seriesOptions.data);
                }
             }
        },
```

The complete demo is here

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nelamurugan/hn7hk1qw/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to do it outside of event handler?

Comment: As an addition to this topic, Here you can see an example how you can make your chart without using drilldown event handler: http://jsfiddle.net/hn7hk1qw/5/

Comment: can we use multiple drilldown function(e) in events{ } highchart ?